# R help add plus 1 to subset of two dataframe and divide int value

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted add +1 to two dataframe int values and divide by each other and take column mean I tried below script it worked as taking subset without taking subset I wanted to do any suggestions

df

```
name  data1 data3 score1 score2 
arun   no    yes    0      20    
jj     yes   yes    40     30  
jimmy  no    no     10     10
```

Using `dput(df)` to provide the data:

```
structure(list(name = c("arun", "jj", "jimmy"), data1 = c("no", 
"yes", "no"), data3 = c("yes", "yes", "no"), score1 = c(0, 40, 
10), score2 = c(20, 30, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

df2

```
name  data1 data3 score1 score2
arun   no    yes    0      10   
jj     yes   yes    20     30  
jimmy  no    no     5      10
```

I want to do the following operations only on integer values:

`df3= df+1/df+1`

What I tried so far: Subsetting:

`df3=(df[,-1:-3]+1)/(df2[,-1:-3]+1)`

Desired output (df3):

```
name  data1 data3 score1 score2
arun   no    yes    1      1.90   
jj     yes   yes    1.95    1 
jimmy  no    no     1.83    1
mean                1.59   1.3
```

Comment: I think the solution you are loooking for is not too complicated, but I am unable to understand your description, escpecially the formulation of your overall goal. Can you please try to make your text easier to understand?

Comment: @Pax is it understandable now

Comment: As @Pax highlighted, please do that. Give one example of your desired output. Also, try to produce the sample data frame with ```dput()```. It will make things easier for everyone.

Comment: It is a lot better now. Bernhard was faster and already has a solution for you. As @Shibaprasadb mentioned, life is less complicated for us, if you provide your data or just a subset of your data by using `dput(df)`, and, then, copy and paste the output.

Comment: Voting to close the question for lack of detail: In the comments to one answer we find that there may be a hundred columns and that some non-numeric columns should be preserved but we do not know whether these are known or need to be detected etc.

Comment: @Bernhard I have mentioned my output how it should look like is it okay now

Comment: @Pax I have edited my question and mentioned output also

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "name  data1 data3 score1 score2 
arun   no    yes    0      20    
jj     yes   yes    40     30  
jimmy  no    no     10     10  ")

df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="name  data1 data3 score1 score2
arun   no    yes    0      10   
jj     yes   yes    20     30  
jimmy  no    no     5      10 ")

df3 <- data.frame(score1 = (df1$score1 + 1) / (df2$score1 +1),
                  score2 = (df1$score2 + 1) / (df2$score2 +1))

print(df3)
```

will yield

```
> print(df3)
    score1   score2
1 1.000000 1.909091
2 1.952381 1.000000
3 1.833333 1.000000
```

Comment: this output I can get it from this also `df3=(df[,-1:-3]+1)/(df2[,-1:-3]+1)`  I need other columns also in this output like name, data1, data3 and I have mentioned only few columns If have 100 columns can not use your above solution

Comment: Great. Please express those requirements **in the question**. Not everyone will read them in the comments to an answer. And everyone should understand the the constraints from the question alone.

Comment: I have mentioned output also is it okay now

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `cbind` function to combine the `dataX` columns with the `scoreX` columns?

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, you have 100s of columns. Assuming the categorical columns are at the beginning and the numerical columns after that, I have solved it like this. This would automate a lot of your work too.

```
#Sample data

df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "name  data1 data3 score1 score2 
arun   no    yes    0      20    
jj     yes   yes    40     30  
jimmy  no    no     10     10  ")

df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="name  data1 data3 score1 score2
arun   no    yes    0      10   
jj     yes   yes    20     30  
jimmy  no    no     5      10 ")


#Specify the number of categorical columns
categorical_cols <- 3

#Assuming the rest are numerical columns, calculating number of numerical columns
numerical_cols <- ncol(df1)-categorical_cols

#Data frame where the result will be stored
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df1), ncol = numerical_cols))

#Run a simple while loop to do the calculations and store the results at the end

i<-1

while (i <= numerical_cols) {
  col_name <- colnames(df1)[1+i+numerical_cols]
  temp <- (df1[1+i+numerical_cols]+1)/(df2[1+i+numerical_cols]+1)
  df3[i] <- temp
  colnames(df3)[i] <- col_name
  
  i <- i + 1
  
}

#Add the other columns of the df1 (or df2) data frame with cbind

df3 <- cbind(df1[1:categorical_cols], df3)
```

```
view(d3)

name data1 data3   score1   score2
1  arun    no   yes 1.000000 1.909091
2    jj   yes   yes 1.952381 1.000000
3 jimmy    no    no 1.833333 1.000000
```

Summarise the mean. It is advisable to not add them to the data frame

```
df3 %>%
  summarise(mean_s1=mean(score1),
            mean_s2=mean(score2))

mean_s1 mean_s2
1 1.595238 1.30303
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As R functions are vectorised, this should work for any number of `score` columns.

```
df3 <- df2
score_cols <- grep('score', names(df1), value = TRUE)
df3[score_cols] <- (df1[score_cols] + 1)/(df2[score_cols] + 1)
df3

#   name data1 data3   score1   score2
#1  arun    no   yes 1.000000 1.909091
#2    jj   yes   yes 1.952381 1.000000
#3 jimmy    no    no 1.833333 1.000000
```